# bring objects to front with zIndex javascript

Tags: javascript, z-index

I have a few draggable objects that are overlaying like a stack of papers. 
I want each object to be lied on top of the stack when picked up.
I have been trying but somehow it is not properly working.

The closest I got was that every time I click one object I needed to click 1 extra time for at the next item until it reaches the front. 
I guess its an easy fix but I fail to find it.

Thanks in advance.

```js
dragElement(document.getElementById("drags"));
dragElement(document.getElementById("drags1"));
dragElement(document.getElementById("drags2"));
dragElement(document.getElementById("drags3"));
dragElement(document.getElementById("drags4"));
dragElement(document.getElementById("drags5"));
dragElement(document.getElementById("drags6"));


 

function dragElement(elmnt) {
  var pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0, pos4 = 0;

  var z_Index = 1;

  elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;


  function dragMouseDown(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
    // call a function whenever the cursor moves:
    document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
    elmnt.style.zIndex = z_Index;


    }

  function elementDrag(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // calculate the new cursor position:
    pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
    pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    // set the element's new position:
    elmnt.style.top = (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
    elmnt.style.left = (elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";


    }

  function closeDragElement() {
    /* stop moving when mouse button is released:*/
    document.onmouseup = null;
    document.onmousemove = null;
    z_Index++;



  }
}
```

```css
#drags, #drags1, #drags2, #drags3, #drags4 {
position: absolute;
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
}
#drags{
background-color: red;
left:34%;
top:12%;
}
#drags1{
background-color: blue;
left:61%;
top:14%;
}
#drags2{
background-color: green;
left:22%;
top:18%;
}
#drags3{
background-color: yellow;
left:35%;
top:29%;
}
#drags4{
background-color: black;
left:40%;
top:20%;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div id="drags"></div>
<div id="drags1"></div>
<div id="drags2"></div>
<div id="drags3"></div>
<div id="drags4"></div>

<div id="see-also">Footer</div>
</body>
```

Comment: you probably want to do as _little_ in JS as possible, so for the zindex, define a class for your not-first elements, and a class for the current in-front element, and then set _those_ useing `element.classList.add/remove/toggle`. Also, rather than setting left/top/etc, you probably want to use the css `transform` property with a `translate(x, y)` value

Comment: Thank you for your reply, 
The class option does not work since I want the clicked object to stay layered over the other objects _but_ the new clicked one and not to return to its default position.

I will try the `translate(x, y)` but actually top/left works great. Does it make a big performance difference?

Comment: yeah: top/left moves "the element" and renders it there, whereas the transform technically keeps the element where it is, and simply moves the rendered result around. As for your z-indexing, it sounds like there is zero reason to use explicit z-indexing, just move the actual DOM node and let the natural layering solve the problem? (protip: if you `appendChild()`/`insertBefore()`/etc. an element that's already in the DOM, all you're doing is _moving_ it, it doesn't duplicate, it just gets inserted in a new position)

Comment: Okay, I am sure I will figure the `transform` out. Haven't yet. I guess you figured I am rather new to javascript. 
I have tried both `appendChild()`/`insertBefore()` but it's not working.

  `function dragMouseDown(e) {
    [...]
   documnet.body.appendChild(elmnt);
    }`
and
  `function dragMouseDown(e) {
    [...]
  let before = document.getElementById("see-also");
   documnet.body.insertBefore(elmnt, before);
    }`

the `before` element referring to the footer-div with the id see-also which is just located in the body, just before the draggable objects

Comment: if you turn your post into a runnable snippet, then people can answer with a copied-and-fixed version of that snippet.

Comment: Good to know, thank you!